# SSAS MDX query with changing values for testing

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm after an MDX query which will change the results every time it is run, regardless of what data is in the cube.

So I'm starting with

```
WITH 
   MEMBER [Measures].[MyMeasure2] AS
   [Measures].[MyMeasure] * 1.0 // replace 1.0 with??
SELECT
    NON EMPTY(...
```

something like RANDOM() would be nice, but that doesn't seem to exist in SSAS. Other alternatives would be things like the current second? That would work if I knew how to retrieve it.

Any other ideas are welcome. The goal is to have a mutating result set so I can test code which models changes over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my SSAS 2008 R2 instance I am able to do this:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[MyMeasure2] AS
    [Measures].[MyMeasure] * RND()
SELECT
    NON EMPTY(...
```

Comment: Perfect, and I feel an idiot because I tried Rand and Random but forgot rnd :/